# Why do I have 3 different pi users?

Tags: ssh, password, user

raspberry pi 3 with raspbian, ssh via macOS

Hi,

I just noticed something awkward. When I tried to login via ssh on my pi, I noticed that I couldn't log in with the password I recently changed with `sudo passwd`.
The password was still the default one. After changing it again, I still wasn't able to log in although no error occurred while changing the password.
Then I tried `passwd` without sudo and it seems to have worked.

But then I noticed that I have 3 pi users???
I have no idea how that happened. I use the pi for running a homebridge server.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: It's not 3 users, it's the same user with 3 terminals open (one of which is graphical desktop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type `sudo passwd` you are running the `passwd` command as the root user, and you are therefore changing the password of the `root` user, not of the user `pi`. Only the third time, when you changed the password using just `passwd`, did you actually change the password of the `pi` user.

The three users you see are just 3 different login sessions for the same user `pi` - likely because you didn't completely log out from one or more sessions. I can see a console login and a GUI login in the list.

Comment: Thanks. Also when I type in users it shows me `pi pi pi`, is that normal?

Comment: Yes, totally normal. `users` reports a very condensed version of `w` - just the usernames. Your 3 users are 1) a console login, 2) a GUI login and 3) a remote login (from a machine called "mimis-air").